# Intersect two list<>

Tags: c#

I EDIT my post, because let suppose that 3 method return rows from a  Database tables
tables are: `docTags` ,  `tags`  and `docs`. docTags is an intermediate table. 
one `doc` (document) can have many `tags` and one `tag` can belong many `docs`
how can I get : `TagKey = "123"`   where  `docTags.Add(new Configuration(1, 1));`

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Configuration
    {
        public  int  DocID { get; set; }
        public int TagID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DocKey { get; set; }
        public string TagKey { get; set; }

        public Configuration(int _docId,string _name, string _docKey)
        {
            DocID = _docId;
            Name = _name;
            DocKey = _docKey;
        }
        public Configuration(int _tagId,string name, string _dockey,string _tagKey)
        {
            TagID = _tagId;
            Name = name;
            TagKey = _tagKey;
        }
        public Configuration(int _tagId, int _docId)
        {
            TagID = _tagId;
            DocID = _docId;
        }
        public static List<Configuration> getDocType()
        {
            List<Configuration> docs = new List<Configuration>();
            docs.Add(new Configuration(1,"contract", "xxx"));
            docs.Add(new Configuration(2,"Action", "yyy"));
            return docs;
        }

        public static List<Configuration> getTagName()
        {
            List<Configuration> tags = new List<Configuration>();
            tags.Add(new Configuration( 1,"contractid", "123"));
            tags.Add(new Configuration(2,"SuperDuper", "332123"));
            tags.Add(new Configuration(22, "rama", "yyy"));
            tags.Add(new Configuration(32, "aktiv",  "123456"));
            tags.Add(new Configuration(42, "data ","xx764fhx"));
            return tags;

        }
        public static List<Configuration> getDocTags()
        {
            List<Configuration> docTags = new List<Configuration>();
            docTags.Add(new Configuration(1, 2));
            docTags.Add(new Configuration(1, 1));
            docTags.Add(new Configuration(1, 22));
            docTags.Add(new Configuration(2, 2));
            docTags.Add(new Configuration(2, 32));
            return docTags;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "without extension methods"? LINQ is the obvious way to do this.

Comment: ok but how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a `Join`:

```
var commonUsers = (from t in tags
                  join d in docs on t.DocKey equals d.DocKey
                  select t)
                  .Distinct();  // to remove duplicates
```

Or another way

```
var commonUsers = tags.Where(t => docs.Any(d => d.DocKey == t.DocKey));
```

The second method is shorter but the first will likely perform better.

Comment: The first may give you duplicate results if docs has two or more of the same `DocKey`

Comment: Both are fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = docs.Intersect(tags);
```

You may need to override the Equals operator for this to work.

Comment: Or you could use the `Intersect` overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx)

Comment: this will not work unless equality for `Configuration` is defined the way the OP is asking (comparing `DocKey`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do this using [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355408.aspx) without overloading the Equals method. You need to create a new class to pass in as the `IEqualityComparer`

```
class ConfigurationComparer : IEqualityComparer<Configuration>
{
    //You can change which string comparer fits your needs best.
    private readonly StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;

    public bool Equals(Configuration x, Configuration y)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(x.DocKey,y.DocKey);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Configuration obj)
    {
         return comparer.GetHashCode(obj.DocKey);
    }

}
```

you then simply do

```
var newList = tags.Intersect(docs, new ConfigurationComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` method and apply it on a filter with a lambda expression to extract items from one list in another using one or more conditions, for sample:

```
var result = needThis.Where(x => needThis2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Or use the extension method [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb460136.aspx), for sample:

```
var result = needThis.Intersect(needThis2);
```